# Is there cleaner way to set dateTime in Kotlin

Tags: android, datetime, kotlin

I'm trying to update DateTime, with kotlin, to make it even cleaner. I tried let, with, apply for example:

```
pickUpDate.apply {
                pickUpDate.hourOfDay().setCopy(hour)
                pickUpDate.minuteOfHour().setCopy(minutes)
                pickUpDate.secondOfMinute().setCopy(0)
            }
```

But didn't worked.
The only thing seems to work is this:

```
pickUpDate = pickUpDate.hourOfDay().setCopy(10)
pickUpDate = pickUpDate.minuteOfHour().setCopy(0)
pickUpDate = pickUpDate.secondOfMinute().setCopy(0)
```

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out:

```
val newDate = pickUpDate.hourOfDay().setCopy(hour)
                        .minuteOfHour().setCopy(minutes)
                        .secondOfMinute().setCopy(0)
```

---

Or even better:

```
fun DateTime.setDayTime(hourOfDay: Int? = null, minuteOfHour: Int? = null, secondOfMinute: Int? = null) {
    var dateTime = this
    if(hourOfDay != null) {
        dateTime = dateTime.hourOfDay().setCopy(hourOfDay)
    }
    if(minuteOfHour != null) {
        dateTime = dateTime.minuteOfHour().setCopy(minuteOfHour)
    }
    if(secondOfMinute != null) {
        dateTime = dateTime.secondOfMinute().setCopy(secondOfMinute)
    }
    return dateTime
}
```

Now you can do

```
val newDate = pickUpDate.setDayTime(hourOfDay = hour, minuteOfHour = minutes, secondOfMinute = 0)
```

---

The reason why your example didn't work is because `apply` returns the current date, but each call to `setCopy` creates a new instance, so the date is immutable and doesn't actually change in place. I guess this is how Joda-Time decided to counter that changing a Calendar in one place shouldn't affect any other places.

Comment: Using `with` instead of `apply` should hence solve the issue, given that it returns the last expression's result (in this case, `secondOfMinute().setCopy(0)`, which returns the new `pickUpDate`)

Comment: I was thinking of `run` but you'd still need to call it with the chain.

Comment: I use it only like 2 times, so i don't think that the extension is neccessary. I liked the first one better :). 
I just thought if there is like a clean way to do it without creating extensions, with just apply or run etc. But @user2340612 explained it nicely. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you're dealing with a fluent API, therefore you should use it just like you would in Java.

```
pickupDate = pickupDate.hourOfDay().setCopy(10)
                       .minuteOfHour().setCopy(0)
                       .secondOfMinute().setCopy(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
 var date = Calendar.getInstance().time
 date.hours = 0
 date.minutes = 0
```

This is how you can set today's time.⚡